# Spring get DB URL from service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to get a DB host URL from other service to configure in my spring.

For example i have my configuration made in my xml in this way

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://49.111.231.832:3306/myDBU"></property>
        <property name="username" value="user"></property>
        <property name="password" value="user123"></property>
    </bean>
```

I've exposed my mysql server outside... Everything is working fine for some days..
As mine being a dynamic ip address it changes at-least once in 3 days, so i would like to write a service wherein i'll update my ip-address in another project and wanted to consume that service to get that ip and inturn wanted to configure that dynamic ip in my above project. In this way i can avoid head ache of changing the code everytime my project and then deploy back again.

Is it possible to do in this way or is there any other way around??

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Publish the IP address to a dynamic DNS service.

If your network device (such as the DSL router) supports it:

1. Register for a dynamic DNS service, such as, [www.dyn.com](http://www.dyn.com).
2. Reserve a domain for yourself.
3. Configure your network device to publish its IP address to the service provider on the domain you registered on step 2.

---

## Option 2: Use a host name in the configuration file instead of an IP address.

1. Use a host name in the configuration file, such as, `<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://db.domain.com:3306/myDBU"/>`
2. Add a host name to IP address mapping in the local `/etc/hosts` file (on Unix, and `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` on Windows) as `db.domain.com nn.nn.nn.nn`, where `nn.nn.nn.nn` is the IP address.
3. Write a background script that updates the host name to IP address mapping whenever a change is detected.
4. Flush the server DNS cache whenever the mapping is changed.

---

With both the options, use the following JVM configuration setting at startup so that your JVM does not cache DNS entries for a very long time (otherwise you will have to restart the JVM every time the IP address changes).

`java -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=<TTL in seconds>`

You can set this value to a small number such as `10` so that the JVM's DNS cache will be purged every 10 seconds.  That way, your application will be unavailable for a maximum of 10 seconds whenever the IP address changes.  If you can live with slow connections, you can even set this value to `0`, in which case the JVM will never cache DNS entries and will always go to the OS to resolve host names.

Comment: Thanks manish for detailed explanation... I'm aware of these options but i do not want to buy any dynamic DNS service as per your option1.
Going with option2, my application is installed on google app engine(3rd party server) and i dont think we can set the env variables there...
So instead cant we have any other option of getting the host name in the configuration file through a webservice??

Comment: There are several free dynamic services. Look at noip.com. If you want a programmatic solution only, implement your own DataSource and use that instead of the one provided by MySQL. Your implementation can fetch the URL from wherever you like.